# SCfigure placed on own page, while figure isn't

Tags: floats, positioning, sidecap

I have a PDF image with a relatively large height. When I place the image into the figure environment, the figure & its caption is displayed at the top of the page such that still some main text appears below the figure in the resulting PDF.

```
\begin{figure*}[htb!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=11.4cm]{Figure2.pdf}
\caption{Some longer caption}
\end{figure*}
```

This is the intended behavior.

To save space, I now want to switch to SCfigure. However, now the SCfigure is placed in the middle on an own page, without any text appearing below or above it anymore:

```
\begin{SCfigure*}[\sidecaptionrelwidth][htb!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=11.4cm]{Figure2.pdf}
\caption{Some longer caption}
\end{SCfigure*}
```

As a result, instead of saving space, I loose space.

Some notes: the height of the caption is smaller than the image height. In the PDF, the total float height (image+caption) seems to be smaller with SCFigure.
I tried different combinations of "htb!", with or without

```
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.9}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.9}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.9}
```

which does not change anything.

Minimal working example (switch comments of begin/end{figure} and SCfigure to see the described effect:

```
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\begin{document}
\Blindtext
%\begin{figure*}[t!]
\begin{SCfigure*}[\sidecaptionrelwidth][t!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=5.4cm,height=12.5cm]{example-image-10x16}
    \caption{\blindtext}
\end{SCfigure*}
%\end{figure*}

\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

While writing the example, I observed that for this "feature" to occur, one seems to have a two-column format...

Comment: If I make a complete example from the snippets you provided, I do not get the behaviour you describe (try https://gist.github.com/TorbjornT/10606b58a0c5fd02b6a189d3ce55e3f7). Can you make a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that does show the problem? You can use `example-image-10x16`or one of the other images from the `mwe` package instead of `Figure2.pdf`, to make the example independent of local files.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. , I added a minimal working example. A two column design seems to be necessary for it to occur. In the meantime, I switched from SCfigure to a normal figure with minipages inside, which works fine for me. Nevertheless, I would prefer a solution with SCfigure since minipages are very manual.